# declare regions to search for image?

Tags: python

```
sunstrike = 'sunstrike.png'
def SunstrikeF():
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('/'):
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=(1970,1887,2081,2003), confidence=0.80):
                print ("Right side")
                time.sleep(0.1)



def SunstrikeD_method():
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('/'):
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=(1859,1891,1963,1992), confidence=0.80):
            print ("Left side")
            time.sleep(0.1)
SunstrikeF()
SunstrikeD_method()
```

Hello,
I have an issue with my code here, when I run this it will only find the first function. The program will find the first image within that region but if the image is moved to the SunstrikeD region of the screen it won't print "Left side".

Also is it possible to declare the regions to search as variables? If so how?
I want the program to use the declared region of the screen and search for any image I plug in and then tell me which side of the screen it's on, right or left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you run a function that is waiting for key being pressed, before this key is not pressed the other function won't run. I advice you to add these two functions together:

```
sunstrike = 'sunstrike.png'
def Sunstrike():
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('/'):
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=(1970,1887,2081,2003), confidence=0.80):
            print ("Right side")
        elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=(1859,1891,1963,1992), confidence=0.80):
            print ("Left side")
        time.sleep(0.1)

Sunstrike()
```

The second part of your question, do you mean something like this?:

```
region1=(1970,1887,2081,2003)
region2=(1859,1891,1963,1992)

regions = [region1,region2]

for region in regions:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=region, confidence=0.80):
        print(region)
        #do something you need, maybe create a dictionary for regions to map them to names
```

The very simple override I can think of is here:

```
#declare regions as xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
region1=(0,0,50,50)
region2=(0,51,50,100)

regions = [region1,region2]

import pyautogui
sunstrike = 'sunstrike.png'
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(sunstrike)

def check_reg(region, x, y):
    if x>=region[0] and x<=region[2] and y>=region[1] and y<=region[3]:
        return True
    return False

for region in regions:
    if check_reg(region, x, y):
        print(region) #print what you need
        break #do not need to continue anymore
```

Comment: else if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(sunstrike, region=(1859,1891,1963,1992), confidence=0.80):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, I get this error when I try it with else if

Comment: @ColterGrantRobinson sorry little mistake, should be elif, yet added a little code how you can create a list of regions and then iterate over them, you can use it in locateOnScreen then in for

Comment: Okay, it's syntax. I change it to elif and I don't get the error but it still won't find the image on the left side.

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering the second part of the question. Still the program will only run the first image search/print of the function though.

Comment: @ColterGrantRobinson from docs: `region argument (a 4-integer tuple of (left, top, width, height))`, are you sure you have set those correctly, does not seem so to me. Maybe all you need is `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pic.png', confidence=0.8)` which returns the location and then use function to map the region to your desired string output?

Comment: I used pulover's macro creator to find the 4 intergers for x and y. It works for the right side so I don't see why the left isn't working. --- Okay so your method to remove the region argument on the elif line worked.

Comment: I get Failed to read sunstrike because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format when trying to run your override code on bottom. Any idea why? It was just using sunstrike.png a second ago. Could it be because I'm trying to run the program through VS?

Comment: @ColterGrantRobinson corrected, added it to quotations so there was problem, I have no pyautogui installed so haven't tried here, should be fine now.